# center contents of float:left

Tags: jquery, center, css-float, css

I want to center the contents of a div that is floated to the left, (incidentally, the contents of this div is other containers that are floated to the left)

See http://jsfiddle.net/KgH8c/ for an example.

I cannot use inline-block due to that not working in IE.

Are there any other solutions?

Thanks,
Wesley

Comment: You want the containers that are floated left to be centered? I am not sure i am understanding the question.

Comment: @Zoidberg, it's a slider type thing, the outer div (floated left) is each slide/page, the inner the contents of that, and yes, these are floated but should be centered if possible...

Comment: Are you sure inline-block doesn't work in IE? I took a look at your CSS. What I saw is that you use `margin: 0 auto;`. Either a margin is `0` or it is `auto`. Both together don't work. Maybe that is the reason why IE can't interpret your CSS right.

Comment: @FlyBy margin: 0 auto is a short-form of margin: 0 auto 0 auto It is used to center non-floated elements.

Comment: @FlyBy the zero is for top and bottom, the auto is for left and right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cannot use inline-block due to that not working in IE.

That's not entirely true. It works completely in IE8 and greater. In IE6/7, it only works on naturally inline elements. Fortunately, there's a really easy way to fix it (to work on for example, `div`s):

```
.inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/KgH8c/1/

Comment: yes, i know it works on natural inline elements, that is why i cannot use it, since the contents are divs, not spans or images.

Comment: In case anyone's curious about the `*` like I was, it's a hack to make that property work only in IE6/7 ([ref](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml))

Comment: @Michael Haren tnx for the info

Comment: @thirtydot - so i don't need to set a height and what not for it to work in IE6? I read an article previously that mentioned that - don't have IE available for testing right now.

Comment: It works as is. Check it out here: http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ + http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/KgH8c/1/show/